# Is there any reason to use Classname.new keyword in ruby other than when creating an instance of an object in a main

Tags: ruby

This class takes in a hash, and depending on the input, it converts temperatures.

```
class Temp
  def initialize(opt={})
    if opt.include?(:cold)
      @colddegree=opt[:cold]
    end
  end
  def self.from_cold(cel)
    Temp.new(:cold => cel) <= instance of class created in class method
  end
end
```

An instance of a class is created inside a class method. Why is it necessary to do so, and what it does it do, what is the reasoning behind it?

- Why would we need to create an instance of a class inside the class instead of the main?
- Why would it be used inside a class method? Can there be a time when it would be required inside a regular object methods?
- What is it calling and what is happening when it is creating an instance inside a class method? what difference does it make?

Comment: You do understand that this new object is actually returned from the method?

Comment: I dont thinks so, what do you mean its returned from the method?Please explain as maybe that might end my confusion

Comment: Ruby's implicit returns help out here.  Most everything you type is an expression that returns a value.  A method with one line of `Temp.new` is going to create a new Temp object (which runs its own `initialize()` method), and then return that initialized `Temp` object. `self.from_cold` creates a `Temp` object with a `:cold` value and then returns that newly initialized object for you to use however you see fit.  `def should_we_panic?; sky.falling?; end` is a simple example.  If the sky is falling, we should panic.

Comment: In ruby, the last line executed's result is the return value of the method.

Comment: @Daniel J. Pritchett, oh that explains it, I didn't know that call runs its own initialized method, ok makes more sense now thanks!

Comment: @Baboon yes I knew that.

Answer (score 9):

Rubyists don't always use the word, but `self.from_cold` is a [factory](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FactoryMethodPattern).  This allows you to expose a `Temp.from_cold(-40)` method signature that programmers consuming your API can understand readily without having to concern themselves with the boilerplate of, say, learning that you have an implicitly required parameter named `:cold`.

It becomes extra useful when you have a work-performing object that needs to be initialized and *then* invoked, such as `TempConverter.new(cel: -40).to_fahrenheit`.  Sometimes it's cleaner to expose a `TempConverter.cel_to_fahr(-40)` option to be consumed by other libraries.  It's mostly just a way of hiding complexity inside of this class so that other classes with temp conversion needs don't have to violate the [Law of Demeter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter).

Comment: thank you for your reply, that gave me better understanding of factory methods but I'm still blurry on the concept of creating an instance anywhere else other than in the main for regular methods.

Comment: I have a Rails app that's importing a bunch of legacy address data that's not entirely standardized.  I use a library called Carmen to provide me with a list of standardized country codes and region codes (e.g. USA -> Tennessee).  Carmen didn't quite solve all of my problems so I wrapped it in a CarmenLookup class that tries a few different fuzzy matching strategies against Carmen's dataset. My ImportAddress class doesn't care though, it just calls CarmenLookup.find_country("Unit ed State") and the messy business of creating and manipulating objects is handled under the hood by CarmenLookup.

Comment: ok, so its done so it wouldn't be obvious to others but I want to understand when is it that I should know that i have to create an instance inside a class method, is it always required to create an instance inside class methods? is the Temp.new(param) calling the initialize method and if so then why can't I just do initialize(:cold => cel) instead of Temp.new(:cold => cel) since we're inside the class. I know this is weird questionbut I want to get the concept..thanks!:)

Comment: You can call Temp.new from anywhere in your app assuming the Temp class has been loaded. It's only hidden inside these factory methods by convention.  Be sure and read that Law of Demeter link above - it gives you some reasons to avoid building an object inside of another class. There's no ironclad rule one way or the other, but whenever you instantiate a foreign class and then start doing a lot to it, you're increasing the coupling between the calling code and the receiving code. This increases the friction when you need to change either class later. That means harder refactors and more bugs.

Comment: While we're way down here in the comments, I want to give my strongest recommendation to Sandi Metz's book Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby.  She'll have you thinking right in no time.

Comment: Will read it for sure because object orientation is hard for me to understand..thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

An important thing to understand is that unlike C#, JavaScript, or C++, new is not a keyword in Ruby. It's just a message which objects of class `Class` understand. The default behaviour is to allocate and initialize a new object of that class, but there's nothing stopping you overriding it, for example:

```
class Foo
  def self.new
     puts "OMG i'm initializing an object"
     super
  end
end
```

So to answer your last question, it makes no difference where `Temp.new` is called. In all cases, it sends the message `new` to the object `Temp` (which is also a class, but remember that almost everything in Ruby is an object, including classes), which creates and returns a new instance.

I'm not going to attempt to answer your other two questions, because the other answer already does.

Comment: you said I can call class.new from anywhere in class but what would the class method do with that object,now that its called from class method

Comment: And the class method can do anything with that object -- the object itself doesn't know or care whether it was created at the top level, or in a class method, or in an instance method, or anything